# Currency converter API displaying empty value

Tags: php

I am currently working on website which require currency converter , I tried few php APi for currency converter but none of them worked getting empty value.

```
    function currencyConverter($currency_from, $currency_to, $currency_input) {
        $yql_base_url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
        $yql_query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("' . $currency_from . $currency_to . '")';
        $yql_query_url = $yql_base_url . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query);
        $yql_query_url .= "&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
        $yql_session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
        curl_setopt($yql_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $yqlexec = curl_exec($yql_session);
        $yql_json =  json_decode($yqlexec, true);
        $currency_output = (float) $currency_input * $yql_json['query']['results']['rate']['Rate'];

        return $currency_output;
    }

    $currency_input = 10;
    $currency_from = "USD";
    $currency_to = "INR";
    $currency = currencyConverter($currency_from, $currency_to, $currency_input);
    echo $currency_input . '' . $currency_from . ' = ' . $currency . ' ' . $currency_to;
?>
```

Comment: Is there a question in there? You don't say what the issue is, _how_ it's not working, what you're seeing etc.

Comment: `http://query.yahooapis.com` won't even resolve for me.

Comment: I don't know that there is still a valid yahoo api for currency conversion... https://developer.yahoo.com/api/

Comment: (Before your next question is probably going to be where you can find an alternative API then, please realize that would be off-topic here: _“Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.”_ – https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)